# Elixir Remove Duplicates From List

Tags: elixir

Would someone be willing to provide some alternate solution to the removal of duplicate values from a List (X) using Functional Programming and Elixir Constructs?

```
X = [1,26,3,40,5,6,6,7] # the 6 being the duplicate
```

The stock solution in my mind for solving this problem, would be to iterate the list (X), and add to a new list (Y) where the key doesn't already exist.

Thank you

Comment: This is element distinctness problem, which is a widely researched problem. We know lower bounds for the problem under some configurations. It can be solved in O(nlogn) by sort + iterate or O(n) on average time + space by using a hash set. The linked question discusses this question.

Comment: @amit Correct thanks - I believe I was looking for an efficient way to solve the problem using Elixir Language Constructs and Functional Programming.

Comment: @amit, I don't think this is a duplicate.  He's asking for an answer in a specific language and the question you suggested he's duplicating is a question regarding algorithmic complexity.  Not exactly the same thing.

Comment: In answer to your question @DaneBalia there's a built in function in Elixir to do what you're looking for.  http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Enum.html#uniq/2 Enum.uniq will remove duplicate items from a collection.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci thank you - exactly what I was looking for and no code needed ;)

Comment: Reopened it, since the focus of the question is not the algorithm, but how to do it in specific language, nevermind the algorithm behind the scenes.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`Enum.uniq` does what you want, for example:

```
iex(6)> Enum.uniq([1,26,3,40,5,6,6,7])
[1, 26, 3, 40, 5, 6, 7]
```

In terms of how you'd implement it you could write a recursive function like so:

```
defmodule Test do
  def uniq(list) do
    uniq(list, MapSet.new)
  end

  defp uniq([x | rest], found) do
    if MapSet.member?(found, x) do
      uniq(rest, found)
    else
      [x | uniq(rest, MapSet.put(found, x))]
    end
  end

  defp uniq([], _) do
    []
  end
end

iex(3)> Test.uniq([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Good suggestion, though HashSet has been deprecated in favor of MapSet.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another possible solution is to use Set when creating collection:

Hashset is now deprecated so instead of using it

```
#[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1] |> Enum.into(HashSet.new) #HashSet<[2, 3, 4, 1]>
```

You should use Mapset

```
#[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1] |> Enum.into(MapSet.new) #MapSet<[2, 3, 4, 1]>
```

Answer (score 2):

Also using MapSet

```
()> "3 3 2 1 1" |> String.split |> MapSet.new |> Enum.to_list
["1", "2", "3"]
```